# Using Rest API to run Oracle BI Publisher report (12.2.1.2)

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run BIP report using REST API using commands as detailed in below link provided by Oracle. I am providing the parameters as below. However the request fails with error 400-Bad Request.

Oracle Link:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/bip/BIPAP/op-v1-reports-%7BreportPath%7D-run-post.html

I also followed the instruction on below link. But for me it is not working.
[Unable to use the REST API services in Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher 12.2.1.2.0 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568341/unable-to-use-the-rest-api-services-in-oracle-business-intelligence-publisher-12/71728513#71728513)

My request details:
URL: http://localhost:port/xmlpserver/services/rest/v1/reports/Publish%2FSTLMTP_I_C_0594_PIIC_RESTAPI/run

Method: POST

Header: Content-Type: multipart/form-data boundary: "Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355" Accept: multipart/form-data Authorization: Basic username:Password (encoded)

Body: (Selected option raw-text. Also tried as raw-XML/JSON/HTML)
--Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355 Content-Type: application/json Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ReportRequest"

{"byPassCache":true,"flattenXML":false,"attributeFormat":"pdf"}
--Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355--

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

400 is bad request.
parameter that you send in ReportRequest have problem.
please check JSON file .
if you have postman check on this.
If your problem is not solved, tell me to send a photo